# Swift calling function displaying funcName(ViewController) instead of arguments?

Tags: ios, swift

In swift i was messing around with some functions in the playground and figured out what I needed to do. So i went ahead and pasted this function into my viewController.swift file however when I went to assign a variable it did this:

[image: http://swiftapprentice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-24-at-10.48.07-pm.png]

(incase the images goes)
This is what autocomplete suggests when I call my function which has 5 arugments in my viewController.swift

```
    let test = template(<#ViewController#>)
```

instead of this which is what it was doing in the playground

[image: http://swiftapprentice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Screen-Shot-2014-09-24-at-10.49.06-pm.png]
(incase images goes)
This is what the autocomplete suggests when i call it in the playground (each object between the <> i can just tab through and change)

```
let test = template(<question: String>, <answerOne: String>, <answerTwo: String>, <answerThree: String>, <answerFour: String>, <correctAnswer: Int>)
```

The only reason I ask is because it was so much easier in the playground because I could easily just hit enter and then tab through each value that needed adding, now it takes much longer, especially when I have to do it 500+ times. Is there something I am doing wrong or anyway I can make my viewController.swift behave like it did in the playgroud? Also the function has a "m" instead of "f" if you look at the pictures on the autocomplete.

EDIT:
Thanks to Alblu I realised the stupid error I was making. I was trying to declare the variable straight under the function (as in not inside any other method). When I went to declare this in the viewDidLoad method it worked perfectly. Rookie error.

Comment: You should paste the content of the code in here, not as an image in a remote site, so that the answer to the question outlives the wordpress uploads you've linked to.

Comment: It just looks like bad design.  You should pass an array of `Question` objects rather than an enormous number of individual arguments

Comment: @AlBlue will do that also, however the images are needed because they show how the autocomplete is changing when I copy and paste it from the playground to the viewController. How would I go about copy and pasting it that? (as in its not the actual code but rather the autocomplete popup)

Comment: There isn't much you can do about that.  When you have more reputation you can include images in your question

Comment: You can show two code samples: this is what you type and this is what the autocomplete suggests.

Comment: @Paulw11 I changed it to accept an array and only 1 argument as well and both are still not autocompleting right. Again, not really a code issue more of a productivity issue as this happens with every function and not just my one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign the variable to something of the same name, and as a result, Xcode is getting confused between what you mean as a variable and what you mean as a function call. One way of solving this is to have different names for your variables and your functions.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake to do that in the picture, this happens no matter what I call the variable and function. Its just weird because it works perfectly in the playground file but as soon as I copy it across it acts differetly

Comment: I suspect you're pasting it in a wrong location, and Xcode thinks you are trying to create a variable instead of in a function body. Please add the entire code to the question instead of small snippets to provide context.

Comment: yep you were right haha I edited my post to show the error I was making.